# Find $P(A \cap B)|B$

Tags: probability

A large group of people is to be checked for two common symptoms of a certain disease. It is thought that 20% of the people possess symptom A alone, 30% possess symptom B alone, 10% possess both symptoms, and the remainder have neither symptom. For one person chosen at random from this group, find the probability that the person has both symptoms, given that he/she has symptom B.

Let $A:=$ possess symptom A, and $B:=$ possess symptom B.

Then, $P(A) = .2$, $P(B) = .3$, $P(A \cap B) = 0.1$, and $P\left(\overline{A\cap B}\right)=0.4$

I am looking for $P(A \cap B|B)$. The multiplicative law of probability that says that 
$$\begin{align}
P(X \cap Y) &= P(X) \cdot P(Y | X) \\
&= P(Y) \cdot P(X | Y)
\end{align}$$

So for my case, $$\begin{align}
P( (A \cap B) \cap B) &= P(A \cap B) \cdot P(B|A \cap B) \\
&= P(B) \cdot P(A \cap B|B)
\end{align}$$

Since I am looking for $P(A \cap B|B)$ I should use the bottom equation. By solving for $P(A \cap B|B)$ I get $$P(A \cap B|B) = \frac{P( (A \cap B) \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{0.1}{0.3} = \frac{1}{3}$$

However, my textbook's answer section says that the answer is 1/4. I don't see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the word *alone* used in this problem. A more traditional way to approach this problem is setting $A = $ possessing symptom A and $B = $ possessing symptom B, but *not* just one of them.

Then
$$\mathbb{P}\left(A\right) = 0.2 + 0.1= 0.3$$
since the $0.1$ still possess symptom A. 
Similarly,
$$\mathbb{P}\left(B\right) = 0.3 + 0.1 = 0.4\text{.}$$
Using your equation with the simplifications,
$$\mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\mid B\right) = \dfrac{\mathbb{P}\left(A \cap B\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(B\right)} = \dfrac{0.1}{0.4} = \dfrac{1}{4}\text{.}$$

Answer (score 4):

We were told that $30\%$ possess symptom $B$ **alone**. So $P(B \setminus A) = 0.3$. Hence:
$$
P(B) = P(A \cap B) + P(B \setminus A) = 0.1 + 0.3 = 0.4
$$